# How can I find an unreachable commit hash in a GIT repository by keywords?

Tags: git

I'm a bit puzzled by a GIT situation.

I'm working on a GIT versioned project and I just noticed that some commits that we thought were already on the master branch weeks ago are actually missing. I remembered these commits were pushed by someone else on a feature branch “feature/something", which does not exist anymore.

I tried to find those missing commits to fix our mistake and to push them on a permanent branch.
In this team, each developer puts the ID of the ticket he is working on in the commit message. So I know for sure ticket id (e.g 1234) is
in the commit message I’m looking for, so I tried:

```
git log --all --grep=1234
git log -g --grep=1234
git log --all | grep 1234
git reflog | grep 1234
```

All of these commands returned nothing.

At this point, I was about to give up and then I remembered our git repo is integrated with Slack, so I searched 1234 in slack history
and found the commits hashes. I immediately tried:

```
git show hash1
git show hash2
```

which surprisingly worked! It displayed all the commit information. So the commits are there, somehow still on my local repository.
So I wanted to double check how I missed them:

```
git reflog | grep hash1
git branch --contains hash1
git fsck --lost-found | grep hash1
```

Nothing.

```
git fsck --unreachable | grep hash1
unreachable commit hash1
```

And here it is, in the unreachable commits list.

But this is a big project and `git fsck --unreachable` returns a tons of commits, how could I have found this lost commit by keyword ?
If we did not have a third party tool logging the git activity, maybe I would have tried piping the output of git fsck back into git show somehow
and grepping on the result but that seems like a lot to do just to find a commit that I know is right here somewhere.

P.S: I’m sorry I can’t share the repo, it’s a private project but the following should reproduce the situation:

User A:

```
git clone <repo>
git checkout -b feature/something
# add something to commit
git commit -m “special-keyword"
git push origin feature/something
```

User B:

```
git clone <repo>
git push origin :feature/something
```

Now User B works for weeks, and then tries to find the commit "special-keyword" pushed by User A.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you delete a branch, you also delete its reflog.  There's a separate reflog for `HEAD` that will retain a reference to commits that were on the deleted branch, but *only if you've had them checked-out*.

The difference between `--lost-found` and `--unreachable` is subtle:<sup>1</sup> see the [git glossary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary/#gitglossary-aiddefdanglingobjectadanglingobject), and/or the illustration below.  In general, using `--lost-found` and/or `--unreachable` will find such commit(s) (and with `--lost-found`, also write IDs into the `.git/lost-found/commit` directory, which I *think* has the side effect of protecting them from garbage collection).

In this particular case, the commit you were looking for was not the tip-most commit of the deleted branch.  That is, suppose before deleting `feature/something` we have this, with the two most recent commits made on the feature branch:

```
A <- B <- C   <-- master
  \
    D <- E    <-- feature/something
```

Now we delete `feature/something`, losing the IDs of commits `E` and `D` both.  Both IDs will show up in the output of `git fsck --unreachable`, but only `E`'s ID will show up (and be saved) by `git fsck --lost-found`, because commit `D` is "reachable" from `E` if/when you restore that commit.

#### Finding your commit

> how could I have found this lost commit by keyword?

It's a bit tricky.  Probably your best bet is using `git show` on all unreachable commits, something like:

```
git show $(git fsck --unreachable | git cat-file --batch-check |
    awk '/commit/ { print $3 }')
```

Now you can search for the keyword(s) in the log messages (or the diffs).  The internal `$(...)` sequence is the method for extracting all the candidate IDs: we just want commits, not tags, trees, and blobs.  Once you have the IDs, all regular git commands (`git log -1`, `git show`, etc) can be used with those.

---

<sup>1</sup>In fact, I just learned it myself writing up this answer.