# git fsck: how --dangling vs. --unreachable vs. --lost-found differ?

Tags: git

I've recently [found about `git fsck`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786972/list-of-all-git-commits), but the linked answers and `git help fsck` give a list of various alternative options,  some of which seem to mean the same to an untrained eye. To be able to use the tool well, I'd love to learn **what's the difference between** below commands?

- `git fsck --dangling`
- `git fsck --unreachable`
- `git fsck --lost-found`

Also, can/should they be used together in some combinations, or better not?

*(As a side note, I'm particularly interested in using this in `git log -G$REGEX $(git fsck --something)`, to cast the net as wide as possible, in a faint hope of finding something I remember writing at some point, but that I can't find with a `git log -G$REGEX -a`.)*

Comment: For unreachable vs lost-found, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31390760/1256452

Comment: @torek thanks! Seems to clarify that part somewhat. Still interested in the --dangling part, however.

Answer (score 18):

Part of the answer is in the [git glossary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary/), where we [find this](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary/#def_dangling_object):

> **dangling object**
>
> An [unreachable object](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary/#def_unreachable_object) which is not [reachable](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary/#def_reachable) even from other unreachable objects; a dangling object has no references to it from any reference or [object](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary/#def_object) in the [repository](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary/#def_repository).

(all links theirs).  Reachability (follow their link if you like) is a basic concept in git's commit graph, where we start with some external reference like a branch or tag name to get starting points within the graph, then follow the outbound edges from each node to find all other nodes.

(There's a glossary entry for [ref](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary/#def_ref) but not for reference, but reference just has its [regular dictionary meaning](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/reference) here.)

I think this is best explained illustratively, though.  Suppose we have a commit DAG that looks like this:

```
     C--D--E      <-- branch-a
    /
A--B--F---G--H    <-- branch-b
    \    /
     I--J--K--L   <-- branch-c
```

Nodes always point left-ish, while possibly also pointing up or down, so node `E`, for instance, points back at `D`, which points at `C` which points at `B` which points at `A`.  (`A` points nowhere: it is a *root* node.)  Node `G` is a merge and points back at both `F` and `J`.  Every node in this graph is reachable: we start from all the external references (branches) and walk left-ish and discover that nodes `A` through `E` are on `branch-a`; nodes `A`, `B`, and `F` through `G` are on `branch-b`; and so on.  (Note that nodes `A` and `B` are on *every* branch.  The fact that a node can be on many branches is one of the things that is a bit unusual about git.  In mercurial, for instance, each node is only ever on *one* branch.  In this particular way, git's branches are fluid while mercurial's are fixed.)

Now let's see what happens if we erase one of the branch labels.  Let's peel off the `branch-a` label first.

Commit `E` no longer has anything pointing to it.  It is *unreachable*, and also—in git's term here—*dangling*.  Commit `D` has only commit `E` pointing to it.  Since `E` is unreachable, `D` is also unreachable, but `D` is *not* dangling, because `E` points to `D`.  `C` is in the same state as `D`.  Node `B`, on the other hand, is reachable from `branch-b` by following `H` to `G` to `F` to `B`, *and* by following `H` to `G` to `J` to `I` to `B`, *and* from `branch-c` by following `L` to `K` to `J` to `I` to `B`.

Let's put the `branch-a` label back (so that `C` through `E` are reachable again) and peel off `branch-c` instead.  This time `L` and `K` become unreachable.  Node `J` remains reachable, though, by starting with `branch-b` and working from `H` to `G` to `J`.  Of the `K` and `L` commits, only `L` is dangling, because `L` points to `K`.

When using `git fsck`, as I noted in that other answer, `--lost-found` "resurrects" (some) dangling objects by writing their IDs or contents into `.git/lost-found/`.

(Remember that commits point back to previous commits, while blobs are just text and never point to anything.  You get dangling commits when you delete a branch, or when rebased-and-thus-abandoned commit chains lose their reflog reference, for instance, so they are pretty normal.  You get dangling blobs when you `git add` a file's contents, then either `git reset` it or `git add` new contents without committing first, so dangling blobs are pretty normal.  `git fsck` does not save dangling tree or tag objects.  Normally there should be no dangling trees: tree objects can only point to more trees and to blobs, and any dangling tree should normally have been pointed-to by a commit; and you have to use `git write-tree` manually, and then never reference the tree, to get a dangling tree.  I'm not sure why tag objects are not resurrected, since accidentally deleting the external reference for an annotated tag *will* result in dangling tag objects, and it might be nice to be able to get those back.)

#### Summary: `git fsck` detection and restoration of dangling or unreferenced objects

Unreachable objects are those not reachable from external references (principally branch and tag names, though there are others like `refs/stash`, used by `git stash`).  Dangling objects are a *subset* of unreachable objects, specifically those with no inbound arcs (in graph theoretic terms).

Adding the `--lost-found` flag will save the IDs of dangling commits—which makes these commits, and hence any additional unreferenced commits, all referenced again—and decompress and make available all dangling blob objects.