# How to show full history of tags in git?

Tags: git, version-control, tags

Tags in git can apparently be moved from one commit to another by simply deleting them and then re-tagging.

For example:

```
git tag -m "Version 1.0" v1.0 abcd123
git push --tags
git tag -d v1.0
git tag -m "Corrected version 1.0" v1.0 1234abc
git push --tags
```

How do I see the entire history of a particular tag?  (In other words, any time a tag with that name was created/deleted, and what commits each one pointed to)

How do I see the entire history of all tags?

Answer (score 10):

They can also be moved by force:

```
git tag -f ...
```

and then force-pushed.

> How do I see the entire history of a particular tag? (In other words, any time a tag with than name was created/deleted, and what commits each one pointed to)

In general, you can't.

If a tag is force-moved and force-pushed and you keep reflogs for tags, you can retrieve previous values from the tag's reflog, until those reflog entries expire.  Deleting a reference (any reference), however, deletes the reflog.

Annotated tags use objects within the repository (in addition to the reference itself).  Deleting the reference deletes *only* the external tag-name reference to the annotated-tag object.  As long as the underlying object itself has not been removed, you can access it by ID.  As an unreferenced object, though, it is subject to the usual garbage-collection rules.  Only if some additional reference (usually another tag-name for another annotated tag) keeps the original annotated-tag object reachable is it guaranteed to remain in the repository.

(There's no fundamental reason a tree object could not point to tag objects, so it would be possible to have a commit object that pointed to a tree that keeps old annotated tags around.  But Git is not built to do this, and has no tools for constructing such things, and it's possible that `git fsck` would consider them erroneous.  So this is more a theoretical exercise: it would theoretically be possible to save, and persist, "old tags" and "tag history" through special commits, probably pointed-to through a new reference name space such as `refs/tagarchive/`, if at least one Git plumbing command and several scripts were written.  Of course this is all pure speculation until someone writes these.  It's not clear how they would be *useful*, either.)

Comment: This is a great answer, but I'm not sure how to apply it; I'm not familiar enough with some of the internals of git.  "As long as the underlying object itself has not been removed, you can access it by ID" - how do I list unreferenced objects?  How do I tell which of them were tags?  How do I tell which particular tag each one was?

Comment: "It's not clear how they would be useful, either" - It seems very valuable to me; tags are commonly used to mark releases.  Just as it is impossible to change code without leaving a record in the revision history (well, kinda - I know about force pushing changes) it should be impossible to change tags without leaving a record, probably also in the revision history.  If this feature really doesn't exist, then I would start using commit messages instead of (or in addition to) tags to mark releases, because they are much harder to modify without a record.

Comment: `git fsck` (https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fsck.html) can find unreferenced objects, including tags. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/36621730/1256452. As for the usefulness: you're not *supposed* to change or delete a tag, ever. That's kind of the point of tags. See https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-tag.html#_on_re_tagging for Linus Torvald's take on this.

Comment: @torek, exactly.  Unless there are less than a handful of active clones, updating a tag is a messy proposition.  I think this is better framed as an access control problem.  In other words, if people are updating tags without due consideration, modifying and deleting of tags should just be rejected with a `pre-receive` hook.

Comment: @torek Not supposed to, lol but what if someone does?  There wouldn't even be any record of it, after garbage collection

Comment: @AlexI: indeed, other than any lingering copies of the original tag on any systems that have it. In which case you have the terrible situation Linus described, where User A says "I have version 2.3, git hash 1234567" and User B says "no, *I* have version 2.3, git hash 89abcde" and at best only one of them is right. ("Two men say they're Jesus, one of them must be wrong...")

Comment: @Chris Interesting.  I don't really want to move tags; I want to make sure they can't be moved, and also retroactively that they _haven't_ been moved.  I'm fairly surprised this problem even exists... of all the weird git design decisions, making erasing tags much easier than rewriting commit history has to take the cake.  Btw, Github doesn't have pre receive hooks.

Comment: @AlexI, you can limit access to the main repository with Github, though.  Limit collaborators to the main repository to people that know what they are doing and use pull requests from cloned repos for other contributors.

Comment: @AlexI, Also, I'm not sure why you think it's hard to re-write commit history; Git provides lots of tools for automating this in different ways.  The thing Git does well is making it easy to verify a particular history; you just need to know the SHA1.  Just keep a list of tag names to SHA1s somewhere and then you can verify that it has not  changed.  You don't really need a history, right?  In other words, if someone changed the tag 4 times since it was originally pushed, you don't care what the intermediate values are, right?

Comment: I agree with @Alexl about the usefulness. Last week I created a version release tag, then realized (before pushing it) that I had put it in prematurely, before an important hotfix. Today I don't see the tag at all. I think I must have deleted the tag, intending to add it back after the hotfix was applied, but then forgot to add it back. I tried today to figure out what happened. It would have been very *useful* to be able to confirm what happened with that tag.

Comment: I understand that there are people with good reasons for saying you should never delete a tag. And there is room for debate. Many aspects of git workflow and policy are up to the local team to decide. The git designers could have decided not to allow the deletion / moving of tags *at all*. But given that changing of tags *is* allowed, the ability to track those changes clearly has a use.