# Can I get back the files in working tree which disappeared resulting from running git restore -s@ -SW?

Tags: git, file, restore, git-worktree

I forgot to add .ai to my .gitignore file, but ran
`$ git add .`
and added quite some `.ai` files to the index.

When I ran
`$ git status`
and saw them, I wanted to remove them from the index.

In haste, I ran
`$ git restore -s@ -SW`
resulting in all of my `.ai` files are gone away from my working tree. I should not have used `W`.

Is there any way in which I can get my `.ai` files back?

Comment: If you never committed them, and you have no backup, then sorry, no.

Comment: @Inigo If they added it to the index, they're in the object folder. If they were never committed, they are still there as dangling objects.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I always assumed that objects were only created upon commit (stashes being like a commit internally). But thinking about it what you say makes total sense (how else would git track index entries?) So I just learned something. Thank you! Upvoting VonC's answer :)

Comment: What is -DW? I doubt you ever said that. Maybe you said -SW.

Comment: Sorry. You are right. I did -SW

Comment: @Inigo `git add` adds objects to the object db. The index is an index, object ids for interesting paths.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, check if you still have access to those files through the "local history" (as recorded by your IDE, not Git)

For instance, the [Local History VSCode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xyz.local-history), as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57151798/6309), can help.

If not, double-check your OS backup feature, like for MacOS [Time Machine status](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/time-machine-restore-3449071/), in case you could restore them from a backup.

Finally, since you have added those files to the index, [check `git fsck`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63435475/6309)

```
git fsck --cache --no-reflogs --lost-found --unreachable HEAD
```

From the SHA1 listed, you can do a [`git show`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show):

```
git show "<SHA-1 REFERENCE TO THE BLOB OBJECT HERE>" > lost_file.txt
```

As noted by [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68310226/can-i-get-back-a-file-in-working-tree-disappeared-by-running-git-restore-s-sw/68313170#comment120747137_68313170):

> Note that you can also find the contents of each of those "unreachable blob"s in the `.git/lost-found/other` directory.
>
> This is often quicker and easier than `git show` since you can `cd .git/lost-found/other`, and then `grep expected-string *` to find the file(s) that have the expected string.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, VonC!
I use vim, and did not use any IDE.
I did not set up backup on my Windows 10.
I ran the git fsck command you recommended, and got the following result. What can I do next, please?

Comment: @ShermanChen No problem: did you manage to restore those files?

Comment: $ git fsck --cache --no-reflogs --lost-found --unreachable HEAD

Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
unreachable blob 0ec003e3d01171ac5e34fa1004b35f8ec75ca598
unreachable commit 71517cfc137a01064a260786891d0b30c8e3e639
unreachable blob ea822e0644c310f5217c0adf5bb2aa56f4ad320d
unreachable blob 86136a72fe190dc1b38f28e83feb83e6433f5b19
unreachable blob 4344ae85545d6f772c50f0a9706dcd2c31d33027
unreachable blob db650a29ec44871ded5972249c6b921de9460bda
unreachable blob f9b55969b1d8665184a1de04d1de98e4e43e6230
unreachable blob 7f5679c6af24e68cb2f5ba609129fb7b954b8856

Comment: @ShermanChen See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63435475/6309 to restore files

Comment: Oh my God! I have got back one of the lost files. That is a miracle! Thank you soooooooooooooo much for your kind help, VonC!!!
A 'show' command has done much much more than a 'show'! It has greatly restored from a wrong 'restore'!
I did not expect that those files could be found back. I posted my question just for possibly a bit hope.
How can I buy at least a coffee for you, VonC?

Comment: @ShermanChen Great job! I have edited the answer to add the `git show`

Comment: VonC, Your great answer will help countless people!

Comment: @ShermanChen: Note that you can also find the contents of each of those "unreachable blob"s in the `.git/lost-found/other` directory; this is often quicker and easier than `git show` since you can `cd .git/lost-found/other` and then `grep expected-string *` to find the file(s) that have the expected string.

Comment: @torek Thank you for this option. I have included  your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @torek there is no .git/lost-found/ directory.

Comment: @ShermanChen: With `git fsck --lost-found`, Git should make one and populate it. Perhaps `--unreachable` disabled this, but I don't think it should.

Comment: @torek Oh. I do not know why, but there is not.

Comment: @ShermanChen What Git version are you using? And on which OS (name and version)?

Comment: @VonC
git version 2.31.1
windows10 Pro version 21H1

Comment: @VonC
@torek
I have installed git version 2.32.0.windows.2 just now, and run 
`git fsck --cache --no-reflogs --lost-found --unreachable HEAD`
again. There is still no `.git/lost-found/`

Comment: @torek I understand that that [`--lost-found` implies `--no-reflogs`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66405506/6309) (and the documentation update attempt [is  not going well](https://github.com/git/git/pull/970#issuecomment-788196473)), but I tried a `git add aFile`, `rm aFile`, `git restore -s@ -SW` (status clean), and `git fsck --cache --lost-found --unreachable HEAD`, and... a [`lost-found` folder](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck#Documentation/git-fsck.txt---lost-found) is nowhere to be, errr, found.

Comment: Curious. Might be a new bug in `git fsck`; I've actually used the whole lost+found thing a few times myself in the distant past.