# Recover a lost file in Git that has been staged but not committed

Tags: git

I did something terribly dumb and lost a huge amount of uncommitted code.
I sincerely ask for your support.

How I lost (summary)

- Had a huge uncommitted/untracked file `lost.py` in local repository.
- `git add lost.py`
- `git push origin branch` ( I forgot `git commit` here)
- `git stash pop` (Thinking I committed my changes, I popped few stashes)
- Above step resulted in merge conflict
- To undo `git stash pop`, I performed `git reset --merge`
- Now I lost `lost.py` from working directory.

Can you please help how to recover the file?

What I tried so far?

- `git fsck --lost-found --unreachable`. This one showed few dangling blob SHAs but none of them show my lost file.

Here are the full sequence of commands from my console that resulted in lost file.

```
me@host:~/Projects/my-project  ⇒ git status
On branch intsite
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        upload_int_site.py ----> This is the lost file.

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
me@host:~/Projects/my-project  ⇒ git add upload_int_site.py 
me@host:~/Projects/my-project  ⇒ git push origin intsite 
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To github.com:My-User/my-project.git
 * [new branch]      intsite -> intsite
me@host:~/Projects/my-project  ⇒ git stash pop
Auto-merging config.ini
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in config.ini
me@host:~/Projects/my-project ⇒ git status
On branch intsite
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   upload_int_site.py

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        both modified:   config.ini

me@host:~/Projects/my-project  ⇒ git commit -m "upload int site"
U       config.ini
error: Committing is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
me@host:~/Projects/my-project  ⇒ git reset --merge
me@host:~/Projects/my-project  ⇒ git status
On branch intsite
nothing to commit, working tree clean
----- Working tree is clean and lost the file here.
```

Comment: Try `git cat-file --batch-check --batch-all-objects | grep blob` to list all blobs.

Comment: It is weird, a simple `git fsck` should have found that.

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara: I've been meaning to get around to testing for new `git fsck` bugs in particular Git versions: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68313170/1256452 and comments... it's possible someone introduced a bug here as these things do happen.

Comment: Try VonC's steps (`git fsck` with extra explicit options) from related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68310226/1256452