Custom git mergetool to merge directories
I have to write custom GUI git mergetool which has to resolve conflicts for all (binary) files in a directory at once, because these files has data interdependencies and consistency has to be ensured. So, I have configured
[mergetool "custommerge"]
    cmd = custommerge "$BASE" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$MERGED"
    trustExitCode = true

When there's a git merging conflict and mergetool is opened by git mergetool -t custommerge dirA/file1 and then I need to checkout base, local and remote versions snapshots for directory dirA (e.g. into a tmp dir). How to do it when git working tree is in the merging conflict state?

For local and remote versions it's possible to do:
git --work-tree /tmp/tmpdir checkout [--ours|--theirs] ./dirA

Note: when using LFS (or any other smudge/clean tool), then it's more safe to checkout worktree root directory ./ always, because .gitattributes from the root directory are ignored when checking out /dirA.
The problem is how to find proper base commit hash ID. By this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69380610/254109 use:
git merge-base --all HEAD MERGE_HEAD

And if it returns just one commit ID, then use it as a base of the current merge conflict. If it returns more commit IDs, then the merge is recursive and it's not possible to get the intermediate commit hash, unfortunately.

Even if multiple merge bases are listed, it is valid to pick one of them as the merge base. Since you are operating with binary files, the "recursive" aspect of the merge is irrelevant for you anyway.
